# how to change the location of a button 2px up/down

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the location of my button some specific amount of pixels up or down **from the current location** of my button. Could you please let me know how I can get the current location?

Thanks

Comment: Look into relative positioning, or just set a margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the approaches: you can use relative positioning

```
button {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

You can also use `margin-top`

```
button {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use margin-top: 2px or margin-top: -2px see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp